# Is there a fast way to compute coefficient of some term of the product of some series'?

Tags: power-series, products

The example in wikipedia is

$$A=1-3x+5x^2-7x^3+9x^4-11x^5+\cdots$$

$$B=2x+4x^3+6x^5+\cdots$$

$$AB=2x-6x^2+14x^3-26x^4+44x^5+\cdots$$

And the term $x^5$ is given by

$$44x^5=(1\cdot6x^5)+(5x^2\cdot4x^3)+(9x^4\cdot2x)$$

So if you wanted the 5th term of $AB$, you would get $44$ in this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $A=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k, B=\sum_{k=0} b_kx^k$, their product $AB$ is known as the series
$$
C=\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_kx^k,
$$
where $c_k=\sum_{j=0}^k a_jb_{k-j}$. Look up [Cauchy product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) for more info.

Comment: Do you know how that would work for multiplying more than two series?

Comment: @user100508 Using $A*B$ to be the cauchy product of two series, you could derive that it is in fact a convolution. In particular, it is associative, so for $A*B*C$, start by computing $D=A*B$ and then $D*C$. I do not know of a more elegant formula other than the one you'd get arranging all the sums this process give you

Comment: Hmm... Would it make anything easier if I told you all the coefficients were 1?

Comment: Yes, if all the coefficients are $1$, you have $(1+x+x^2+x^3\dots)^2=1+2x+3x^2+\dots (i+1)x^i\dots$  Also if you can formally sum the series you can do things.  $(1+x+x^2+x^3\dots)^2= (\frac 1{1-x})^2$ and you can use Taylor series techniques.  This goes under the name generating functions.

Comment: @user100508 Yes there is someting to do in that case, perhaps ask a new question for that particular case.